# Google drive getFolders sorted by Name and not by last modified

Tags: api, sorting, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have this google drive script that I want to use to get list of all files and subfolders of a particular drive.

I have the base code but the problem is it isn't being sorted by name but based on last modified file. How can I change it?

```js
var childFolders = parent.getFolders();
```

Comment: For reference, this is the site I am referring to: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive

Comment: i think that once you have the files in a data structure you can use the information of each file to sort them. You can use the provided methods available on data structures for sorting, with suitable complimentary comparing routines.

Comment: Hey @hellokitty were you able to solve your issue with my answer? Please consider [upvoting/accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it in case it was useful to you. Otherwise, kindly describe the issue you are having,  so we may help you. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

An easy solution is to replace your `getChildFolders()` function for the following:

```js
function getChildFolders(parent, docu) {

  var childFolders = getSorted(parent.getFolders());

  for (var i=0; i<childFolders.length; i++) {

    var childFolder = childFolders[i];
    var childFolder_name = childFolder.getName();

    docu.appendParagraph(childFolder_name);

    var files = getSorted(childFolder.getFiles());

    for (var j=0; j<files.length; j++) {
      var files_name = files[j].getName();

      docu.appendListItem(files_name);
    }

    // Recursive call for any sub-folders
    getChildFolders(childFolder,docu);
  }
}

function getSorted(it) {
  var l = [];

  while (it.hasNext()) {
    var f = it.next();
    l.push(f);
  }

  return l.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.getName() < b.getName()) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (a.getName() > b.getName()) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  });
}
```

The idea is that right after getting children folders/files, those are ordered in the auxiliary function `getSorted(it)`, by using the [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function.

Alternatively, you could use the `orderBy` parameter of the [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) method of the API.

Answer (score 0):

this is the code I found but with some modifications on my side. I'm not sure how I could incorporate sorting here:

```js
/* Change the FOLDER NAME to generate tree for any specify folder */

function generateFolderTree() {

  var docu =  DocumentApp.create('Document');

   // If you want a tree of any sub folder
   var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Folder name").next();

   // If you want to search from the top (root) folder
   //var parentFolder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();

   getChildFolders(parentFolder,docu);


}


function getChildFolders(parent,docu) {

  var childFolders = parent.getFolders();

  while (childFolders.hasNext()) {

    var childFolder = childFolders.next();
    var childFolder_name = childFolder.getName();

    docu.appendParagraph(childFolder_name);

    var files = childFolder.getFiles();

    while (files.hasNext()) {

    var files_name = files.next().getName();

    docu.appendListItem(files_name);

    }

    // Recursive call for any sub-folders
    getChildFolders(childFolder,docu);

  }

}
```

Comment: Kindly consider editing your original answer and inserting the code there. The answer section is dedicated to **only** answers in Stackoverflow. Welcome to the community & have a good day!